# Ngx-charts can't load line chart from feed correctly, works with local file

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

I am having a char initialised. Works good so configuration is properly set up and dependency installed. I followed example for line-chart and used data provided here: https://swimlane.gitbooks.io/ngx-charts/content/charts/line-chart.html

Works correctly.
Problem is when I load a data from API feed, my graph acts strange, tooltip is not disappearing and whatever route i click it loads in same window, aka something is broken:
[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/3589518/31313300-bd04ad70-abd6-11e7-9e71-3d7744d689f4.PNG]

Now this is the data from feed:

```
{
    "currentWeight": 80,
    "bodyMassIndex": 0,
    "exercisesProgress": [
        {
            "name": "Bench Press",
            "series": [
                {
                    "name": "10/10/2017",
                    "value": 66
                },
                {
                    "name": "12/10/2017",
                    "value": 78
                },
                {
                    "name": "15/10/2017",
                    "value": 61
                },
                {
                    "name": "18/10/2017",
                    "value": 79
                },
                {
                    "name": "19/10/2017",
                    "value": 74
                },
                {
                    "name": "22/10/2017",
                    "value": 68
                },
                {
                    "name": "23/10/2017",
                    "value": 75
                },
                {
                    "name": "17/11/2017",
                    "value": 76
                },
                {
                    "name": "23/11/2017",
                    "value": 62
                },
                {
                    "name": "23/12/2017",
                    "value": 71
                },
                {
                    "name": "23/01/2018",
                    "value": 68
                },
                {
                    "name": "23/02/2018",
                    "value": 70
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I then initialise data like this in graph:

```
<ngx-charts-line-chart
      [view]="view"
      [scheme]="colorScheme"
      [results]="dashboardModel.exerciseProgress"
      [gradient]="gradient"
      [xAxis]="showXAxis"
      [yAxis]="showYAxis"
      [legend]="showLegend"
      [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
      [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
      [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
      [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
      [autoScale]="autoScale"
      (select)="onSelect($event)">
</ngx-charts-line-chart>
```

Thing doesn't work.
When I put data directly into ts.file:

```
export var multi = [
  {
      "name": "Bench Press",
      "series": [
          {
              "name": "10/10/2017",
              "value": 66
          },
          {
              "name": "12/10/2017",
              "value": 78
          },
          {
              "name": "15/10/2017",
              "value": 61
          },
          {
              "name": "18/10/2017",
              "value": 79
          },
          {
              "name": "19/10/2017",
              "value": 74
          },
          {
              "name": "22/10/2017",
              "value": 68
          },
          {
              "name": "23/10/2017",
              "value": 75
          },
          {
              "name": "17/11/2017",
              "value": 76
          },
          {
              "name": "23/11/2017",
              "value": 62
          },
          {
              "name": "23/12/2017",
              "value": 71
          },
          {
              "name": "23/01/2018",
              "value": 68
          },
          {
              "name": "23/02/2018",
              "value": 70
          }
      ]
  }
];
```

and then initialise it like:

```
<ngx-charts-line-chart
      [view]="view"
      [scheme]="colorScheme"
      [results]="multi"
      [gradient]="gradient"
      [xAxis]="showXAxis"
      [yAxis]="showYAxis"
      [legend]="showLegend"
      [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
      [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
      [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
      [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
      [autoScale]="autoScale"
      (select)="onSelect($event)">
</ngx-charts-line-chart>
```

Then it works.
I am not sure what is different:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are loading data from api call which is async is takes some time to return and initilize the  the graph and think that what ngx chart dosent like.

So you need to check  something like this
 `dashboardModel?.exerciseProgress` 
or even put the whole thing inside a `ngIf = "dashboardModel"`

Comment: i put div and ngif, thanks, is there any docs i can read about this behaviour ?

Comment: Docs on ngIf is enough i guess , The reason for this behaviour is the data loaded from API is async and it takes times to reach your component and in order to use in your template you need to wait for the data so you can use a  `?` safe operator or a `ngIf` for this . To wait for the data to arraive if you the data passed to chart is undefined