# Ngx-charts can't load bar charts directly with async pipe in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, angular-pipe, ngx-charts

My problem is similar to this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46629702/1712016)

When I use async pipe to observe data from firebase and show it in chart, I can see the chart but prompt null error in console. Without async pipe, all errors are gone but I can't fetch data (duh it's async data). Help me please.

[image: Barchart]

[image: Barchart code]

[image: Error]

[image: Empty chart]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Cause

This is happening because the component cannot work with `null` values for `results`.

## Why?

Async pipe is, as you say, used when you do not want to (or do not need to) subscribe in the component code, but do it in the template instead. Pipe, however, is a pure function: is has to return *something* each time it's called.

When th async pipe is called before data has arrived from the server, the pipe returns `null`, having no better value to offer.

Based on the screeshot of the error trace, it looks like `ngx-charts-bar-vertical` does not work when `results` is set to `null` and it breaks then.

## A fix

You need to not render the bar chart component at all while data is not present. You can do this by utilizing the `NgIf` directive, which allows you to do a binding in the template with `as`. Super-useful for exactly these cases where you want to conditionally show a part of the template, but then re-use this value again.

```
<ngx-charts-bar-vertical *ngIf="surveyAnswers | async as answers"
                         [results]="answers"
></ngx-charts-bar-vertical>
```

While `surveryAnswers` observable doesnt emit anything, the component will not be rendred, thus there will be no error. When it emits, `async` pipe will catch that, trigger CD and it won't be `null` anymore -- it will be a truthy value, which then gets fed into a variable called `answers` that we use to feed into the `results` input of the component.

Comment: this is spot on answer. save this answer for future reference. I was trying to convert from observable to array and it makes me more confused. Thank you so much for this answer.

Comment: I have the same exact issue but still getting same errors. I'm getting data from my store using `ngrx`. I'm selecting data in my constructor and assigning it to an `Observable<ChartData>`.

Comment: any thoughts on that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53609566/input-property-does-not-work-with-ngx-charts-template ?