# Input property does not work within ngx-charts template

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47826641/ngx-charts-cant-load-bar-charts-directly-with-async-pipe-in-angular/47827083#47827083) I did come up with code below that works fine:

```
result: any;
ngOnInit() {
  this.result = getResult();
}

<ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked
    *ngIf="(result | async) as results"
    [results]="results"
>
</ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked>
```

Now I want to pass result as an input parameter:

```
@Input() result: any;

<ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked
    *ngIf="(result| async) as results"
    [results]="results"
>
</ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked>
```

but it is just does not work this way, the chart just does not get displayed also I can't see any errors in console. However I come up with the trick by assigning input value to another component property I declared:

```
data: any;
@Input() result: any;

ngOnInit() {
  this.data = this.result;
}

<ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked
    *ngIf="(data| async) as results"
    [results]="results"
>
</ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked>
```

So this way it works but I wonder how would you do it properly without introducing new variables and doing hacks like `this.data = this.result;`